# Misclassification cost depending on particular classes involved

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Suppose one has 5 classes and wants to classify images, e.g.:

```
import tensorflow as tf

classes = ['Apple A','Apple B','Pear A','Pear B','Pear C']
model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNet(weights=None, classes=len(classes))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(...)
```

Getting the specific apple variant wrong should be less costly than confusing an apple for a pear. How would one go about penalizing e.g. `Apple A <-> Apple B` or `Pear B <-> Pear C` less than `Apple * <-> Pear *`?

Comment: Something like sample weights?

Comment: As far as I understand, `sample_weights` (or `class_weight`) only allow to adjust the importance of specific samples (or entire classes)? I would need to to adjust the loss based on both `y_true` and `y_pred`.